# Bast Way On Passing Query Parameters to Solrnet

Tags: search, solrnet

I have been working on making a Search using Solrnet which is working the way I want to. But I just would like some advice on the best way to pass my query parameters from my web page into Solrnet.

What I would ideally like to do is pass my query string parameters similar to how this site does it: http://www.watchfinder.co.uk/SearchResults.aspx?q=*%3a*&f_brand=Rolex&f_bracelets=Steel&f_movements=Automatic.

As you can see from the sites query string it looks like it is being passed into SolrNet directly. Here is I am doing it at the moment (facet query segment):

```
public class SoftwareSalesSearcher
    {
        public static SoftwareSalesSearchResults Facet()
        {
            ISolrOperations solr = SolrOperationsCache.GetSolrOperations(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SolrUrl"]);

        //Iterate through querystring to get the required fields to query Solrnet
            List queryCollection = new List();
            foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Keys)
            {
                queryCollection.Add(new SolrQuery(String.Format("{0}:{1}", key, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[key])));
            }

            var lessThan25 = new SolrQueryByRange("SoftwareSales", 0m, 25m);
            var moreThan25 = new SolrQueryByRange("SoftwareSales", 26m, 50m);
            var moreThan50 = new SolrQueryByRange("SoftwareSales", 51m, 75m);
            var moreThan75 = new SolrQueryByRange("SoftwareSales", 76m, 100m);

            QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions
            {
                Rows = 0,
                Facet = new FacetParameters {
                    Queries = new[] { new SolrFacetQuery(lessThan25), new SolrFacetQuery(moreThan25), new SolrFacetQuery(moreThan50), new SolrFacetQuery(moreThan75) }
                                            },
                FilterQueries = queryCollection.ToArray()
            };


            var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, options);

            var searchResults = new SoftwareSalesSearchResults();

            List softwareSalesInformation = new List();

            foreach (var facet in results.FacetQueries)
            {
                if (facet.Value != 0)
                {
                    SoftwareSalesFacetDetail salesItem = new SoftwareSalesFacetDetail();

                    salesItem.Price = facet.Key;
                    salesItem.Value = facet.Value;

                    softwareSalesInformation.Add(salesItem);
                }

            }

            searchResults.Results = softwareSalesInformation;
            searchResults.TotalResults = results.NumFound;
            searchResults.QueryTime = results.Header.QTime;

            return searchResults;
        }       

    }
```

At the moment I can't seem to see how I can query all my results from my current code by add the following querystring: q=*:*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "parameters being passed into SolrNet directly". It seems that watchfinder is using some variant of the [model binder included in the SolrNet sample app](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SampleSolrApp/Models/Binders/SearchParametersBinder.cs).

Also take a look at the [controller in the sample app](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SampleSolrApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L72) to see how the SolrNet parameters are built.

Comment: Ah thanks Mauricio. That looks like what I want I'm trying to achieve. I will give that a go!